# Any databases with CEO letters and shareholder letters?

Tags: data, database, data-mining

I am researching disclosures on CEO letters and Shareholder letters present in annual reports of listed companies in the London Stock Exchange.

Can someone recommend a database where the annual reports would be available in plain text? Or at least where all the PDFs could be downloaded as a whole package? All I've found until now was the website [AnnualReports](http://www.annualreports.com/Companies?exch=9) but I believe someone must have done already this work :)

Comment: @Can you clarify what you mean by disclosures? Can you give an example?

Comment: Disclosures is any information that might have value for report readers, be it shareholders, employees, investors, etc. For example: "We have implemented a energy saving policy this year, reducing 20% the energy costs and CO2 emissions in our facilities" would be a disclosure.
See more here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3665456?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents